# How to select variables in a nested list in R?

Tags: r, list, indexing

Let's say I have a list named `test`:

```
test <- list(list(var1 = 1, var2 = "test"))
```

How can I retrieve the value of `var1` and `var2`?

```
> test$var1
NULL
> test[1]$var1
NULL
```

Comment: `test[[1]]$var1`.  You might find it helpful to read `help("Extract")`.

Comment: This also might be helpful in understanding the root issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `x[[…]]` (instead of `x[…]`) to select individual elements from a list by index.

So, in your case, you can use

```
test[[1L]]$var1
# [1] 1

# or
test[[1L]][["var1"]]
# [1] 1
```

Unlike the `purrr:::pluck()` solution this has no external dependencies. And, if that matters (it rarely does!), it’s also by far the most efficient solution.<sup>1</sup>

Another way to use `[[` on lists is [recursively](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html#:%7E:text=%5B%5B%20can%20be%20applied%20recursively%20to%20lists). Unfortunately, however, this requires vector indexing, so it doesn’t work with mixed index types (in your case `1` and `"var1"`). But if you have only numeric indices, say, you can write:

```
test[[c(1L, 1L)]]
# [1] 1
```

---

<sup>1</sup>

```
bench::mark(
  a = unlist(test)["var1"],
  b = test[[1L]]$var1,
  c = pluck(test, 1L, "var1"),
  check = FALSE
)
# # A tibble: 3 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 a            1.48µs   1.93µs   450574.        0B     45.1  9999     1
# 2 b              82ns    164ns  6085391.        0B      0   10000     0
# 3 c            1.97µs   2.21µs   442238.        0B     88.5  9998     2
```

Answer (score 3):

I find [`purrr::pluck`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/pluck.html) gives a readable way of indexing into nested lists:

```
library(purrr)

pluck(test, 1, 'var2')
[1] "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `` `[[` `` along with `lapply` like below

```
> test <- list(list(var1 = 1, var2 = "test"), list(var1 = "xxx", var2 = 5))

> lapply(test, `[[`, "var1")
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] "xxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
unlist(test)
var1   var2 
 "1" "test"
```

And later on access the members of this named vector:

```
unlist(test)["var1"]
var1 
 "1"
```

Definetely it has some limitations (for instance type cast) but is simple, fast and does not require external packages and thus may be useful for some cases.

**Appended** upon comments of KonradRudolph
I have to repeat my disclaimer and prove every word from it.

1. Simple. I think it is obvious that it does not require understanding of functional programming.
2. Fast.

see theese benchmarks:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(unlist(test)["var2"], 10000)
Unit: nanoseconds
                 expr  min   lq mean median   uq   max neval
 unlist(test)["var2"] 3600 3700 3980   3700 3800 22200   100
                10000    0    0    0      0    0     0   100
```

in comparison to @andrew_reece (c):

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(pluck(test, 1, 'var2'), 10000)
Unit: nanoseconds
                   expr  min   lq mean median   uq   max neval
 pluck(test, 1, "var2") 4900 5000 5430   5100 5200 28700   100
                  10000    0    0    0      0    0     0   100
```

3. Does not require external packages.

Comment: As your output shows, **`unlist()` is a bad idea** since it coerces the items of different type to a common type. A correct solution should return `1`, but yours returns `"1"`, i.e. *the wrong result*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Please kindly refer to my disclaimer in my answer. I paid OP's attention to the type cast you are writing about. Moreover I selectted `var1` intentionally as this type cast is explicitly shown. I also wrote that inspite of certain disadvantages this method did also have some advantages and applications for some cernain (probably limited) cases. OP may select way he needs to solve their real problem selecting from different options

Comment: I saw the disclaimer, and that’s why I ended up not downvoting the answer (which is otherwise just plain wrong and unhelpful, and should thus be downvoted pretty much by definition). Contrary to what you wrote, there are *no* advantages to this method (what do you think the advantages are?).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Please see the appendix to my answer. I had to unlist :) advantages stated in my disclaimer.

Comment: I think I see the issue — you are working on the assumption that this is the only base R way of accomplishing this; but it’s not, see the comment under the question. The correct way has all the advantages you list, and is (substantially: more than an order of magnitude!) faster. Anyway, using `purrr::pluck()` also doesn’t require understanding functional programming (though using R well requires that in general) so I’m not sure why that point was included.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Certainly I saw the comment. The difference is that I gave the way to get access to the whole (reshaped) structure not certain specific members from it.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by this (what benefit you think this provides).